# Custom class archiving in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I would like to archive and unarchive a custom object in swift, something like this:

```
class Line : NSObject, NSCoding  {

    var start : CGPoint


    init(start _start: CGPoint) {
        start = _start
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // 1 - compile time error
        self.start = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("start") as CGPoint
    }

    override init() {
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        // 2 - compile time error
        aCoder.encodeObject(start, forKey: "start")
    }
}
```

The 1. compile time error is:
Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

The 2. compile time error is: 
Extra argument 'forKey' in call

How to archive and unarchive a CGPoint, I know CGPoint is a struck and this is the problem, but how to solve it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can archive/unarchive a CGPoint using :

```
encodeCGPoint:forKey:
```

and

```
decodeCGPointForKey:
```

More information here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCoder/encodeCGPoint:forKey:

Answer (score 1):

May be you can convert CGPoint to NSValue.

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    var cgPointAsObject:NSValue = NSValue(CGPoint: start)
    aCoder.encodeObject(cgPointAsObject, forKey: "start")
}
```

Similarly reverse process convert NSValue to CGpoint while decoding.

Answer (score 0):

In `swift3` there is some `func` changed, to do like this:

```
class UserModel: NSObject,NSCoding {

var username:String = ""
var password: Int = 0

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()

}

override init() {

}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

    }

}
```